# Include own answers in calculations

Tags: discussion, badges

I have heard that my own answers are not included in my badge calculations? This seems wrong to me as I have answered my own, old unanswered, questions and should be an Unsung Hero in that regards.

Not a big badge hunter, but interested in reasoning nonetheless.

Comment: To which badge are you referring?

Comment: Overall question, but Unsung Hero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you answer someone else's question and it's accepted, you'd normally get an upvote as well and **unsung hero** is a consolation for providing a helpful answer that nobody upvoted. If you've answered your own question, there's [no such guarantee](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/) that the answer is helpful.

> Although it’s fine to ask and answer
> your own question — this is
> specifically encouraged in the faq —
> you’ll have to rely on the community
> to upvote your answer and validate it
> as correct. You, sir (or madam), are
> biased. Of course your answer to your
> own question will be the best possible
> answer. You wrote the darn thing!

While that blog entry is out-of-date and not about exactly the same topic, it still explains why having a self-accepted answer doesn't mean much by itself.

Comment: My issue is that I had a couple questions that were unanswered for months. With my gained experience I was able to provide an answer. No worries, just curious.